# vue and eslint is only linting changed files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

We are using vue-cli with the eslint plugin and we have an .eslintrc config like this:

```
const devOff = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'warn';

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': devOff,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
};
```

When we run `npm run build` the first time we get an error and that's fine as eslint should report errors when building for production.

> warning: Unexpected console statement (no-console) ...

When we run `npm run build` again without changing anything, the build runs fine. It seems to me eslint is caching already parsed files regardless of having errors or not.

I found the CLI optin --cache in the [eslint guide](http://%20https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#options) but I couldn't manage to set this option in vue.config.js nor .eslintrc.js

How can I set up vue/eslint to fail repeatedly the production build if we have any linting errors in any file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve this issue in all my projects:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports =
{
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    config.module.rule('eslint').use('eslint-loader').loader('eslint-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      delete options.cacheIdentifier;
      options.cache = false; // otherwise on each restart cached errors won't be shown !!!
      return options;
    });
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').loader('vue-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      delete options.cacheDirectory;
      return options;
    });
    config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like a very complicated solution for something which should be the default.

Comment: You can open an issue on Github but I doubt it will get attention - other people have already reported the bug and it is still not resolved.

Comment: Do you have any link to other so questions like this or a link to a bug report??

Comment: There is a bug report already: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3065

Comment: Yes, there is - and no official bugfix, only unofficial workarounds.